# show hide multiple class with jquery - fade/smooth

Tags: jquery, hide, show, fade, smoothing

I found this http://jsfiddle.net/uB9Fb/

And it does what I want perfectly, but how can I make it fade in, smoothly?

```
$('.commentsToggle').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".comments").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.commentsToggle').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".comments").fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: (+1) @Tor-Arne Njaamo, for a better UX instead of fade (the result is too jumpy, imagine you have long comments...) use slideToggle: http://jsfiddle.net/uB9Fb/94/ The user can follow with the eye the changes on page, while after a fade... *bam*!

Comment: Yep, I agree with Roko - slide looks much better and smoother